# Css hover customization in to xml

Tags: html, css, xml, eclipse

I've a (portion of) css like this:

```
.my_content{

   background-image : url("../icons/my_small_corner.png");
    background-position : top left;
   background-repeat : no-repeat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
   border-top-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-color: #241882; 
    background-color: #0071C5; opacity: .3;
   /* float : none; */
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top : 25%;
    left : 30%;
   width : 20%;
    height : 25%;
}

#text_c .text {
    font-size: 17pt;
    color: #0066FF;
}
```

and this is the xml (not html! as I'm customizing the eclipse welcome page) I use:

```
  <group id="text_c" style-id="my_content">
     <group id="page-links" >
        <text>My text!!!!!</text>
     </group>
  </group>
```

that draw a rectangle with borders of 3px each, that's fine!

I'd like to highlight the borders to 7px (for example) if the mouse goes over it! 
I tried this without success:

```
.my_content:hover {

    border-bottom-width: 10px;
   border-top-width: 10px;
    border-left-width: 10px;
    border-right-width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The my_content class definition in your CSS file, does it have:

```
my_content:hover{}
```

or

```
.my_content:hover{}
```

If the period character `.` is missing that may be prevent hover css from executing. The code snippet you have above does not have the period `.` character. Not sure if that is just a copy/paste error.

Comment: Could you please try `border-bottom: solid 3px #241882;` then for hover `border-bottom: solid 10px #241882;` instead of separated css border properties? Also do you have these css definitions in root.css or do you have a separate css file?

Comment: I have the default theme "slate" and I was able to see css hover changes for the Welcome page by editing root.css in "path\to\Eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.701.v20150204-1123\themes\slate\html\root.css"

Comment: Are you certain this css file is linked using the style or alt-style properties in the xml? [Defining intro content](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_intro_define_content.htm). The trick is just making sure the correct stylesheet for the active theme is targeted.

Comment: how can I check? but I think so as any change is reflected

Comment: So according to [Customize Welcome Page](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp), if you click the Customize page button you should be able to see the current theme that is in action (if any). Knowing that theme, you could find the corresponding root.css file and add your css declarations accordingly. The Customize page button looks like a mini checklist in the top right hand corner of the Welcome Page near the minimize button. Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: this looks like more a css/xml problem to me ... but so far I'm just guessing